# Set admin-like user for firebase realtime-database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, web-applications

im maintaining an older react web-app that uses a firebase realtime-database to store its data. I want to restrict the access to the database, so that only my react app can read from and write into the database. Is there a way to set up an admin-like login (kinda like with sql-databases) to authenticate my application?

I don't want to authenticate other users or enable them to register, I just want to ensure that only the web-app can edit and modify the database.

I've tried to experiment with the firebase authentication-methods but they don't seem to be what im looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to authenticate other users or enable them to register, I just want to ensure that only the web-app can edit and modify the database.

That's not possible.  The only way to control access to a Realtime Database instance (while allowing direct access from web and mobile clients) is using Firebase Authentication to identify users, in combination with security rules that determine which users can access which data.  Otherwise, anyone with an internet connection will be able to read or write the database.